# Ubuntu overnight repositories failure

Tags: networking, apt, package-management, updates, repository

```
sudo apt-get install openvpn
[sudo] password for XXXXXXXXXXXX:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libllvm4.0 thunderbird-locale-en thunderbird-locale-en-gb
  thunderbird-locale-en-us
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libpkcs11-helper1
Suggested packages:
  easy-rsa
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libpkcs11-helper1 openvpn
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
Need to get 496 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,318 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 libpkcs11-helper1 i386 1.11-5
  Could not connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.26). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main i386 openvpn i386 2.3.10-1ubuntu2.1
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main i386 openvpn i386 2.3.10-1ubuntu2.1
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/pkcs11-helper/libpkcs11-helper1_1.11-5_i386.deb  Could not connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.26). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openvpn/openvpn_2.3.10-1ubuntu2.1_i386.deb  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: It looks like your network connection was DOWN when `sudo apt-get install openvpn` was executed. Try again with the network UP. `ip link show | egrep -q 'UP,LOWER_UP.* state UP' && echo UP || echo DOWN'`

Comment: It took a while to figure out, but Ubuntu seems to activate the wired connection and the wireless at the same time. That seems to have fixed it.  I haven't checked in detail, but I think that's what's happening. Thanks for the help, everyone!

Comment: @JamesPatterson How did learning that wired and wireless connections are up at the same time solve the problem?